# How can we wrap the line based on border size of windows browser?

Tags: css

How can we wrap the line based on border size of windows browser?

Say I have a long text. The text can be wrapped based on the windows size.
If I resize the windows, I can be wrapped dynamically.

In order word, What i want to do is that there is no horizontal scrolling. Only vertical scrolling but the text can be wrapped automatically based on windows size.

How can do this in CSS?

Comment: Didn't quite get you. What's your use case, or and prototype?

Comment: @Leo, Thanks i have edited by question. basically don't want horizontal scrolling on my text

Comment: overflow-x: hidden ?

Comment: @avramm, i have tried, the scollbar is disabled but the text does not wrap automatically.

Comment: can you provide some code ?

Comment: Could provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just described a block level element.  It will wrap when the browser is resized.

Comment: This is not an answer. It should have been a comment.

Comment: No it is the correct answer. What I do is the add a block element outside the text.  Thanks. I am too new on CSS!